# Laptop VGA output discoloration/tint after DIY cleaning

Tags: video, vga

I have an ASUS N53SN and I've had used the VGA output port on it to project my screen to a bigger LCD monitor without any problem. Recently, I decided to disassemble my laptop for reapplying thermal paste and cleaning it up. After that procedure, the picture on my laptop screen is fine but the one on any display connected to the VGA port looks tinted (blue or green) and discolored. It shows red instead of black, dark green as orange, lime as yellow, etc. All colors don't have their red channel as in RGB, only green and blue. I also noticed this in BIOS.

I have tried reconnecting the VGA cable shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKZig.jpg) image, no improvements or any changes.

How can I detect the problem or troubleshoot it? Does it have anything to do with LVDS connector? Can I fix it on my own?

Comment: It does sound as if red connection is failing. But before doing anything complex, can you check if the cable is solidly connected to both laptop **and monitor** ? Also try a second DB15/VGA cable (Borrow one at work if needed) to make sure it is not one of the easy and cheap fixable solutions before looking at other problems. (having said that, the timing after dis- and re-assembly is not a good sign).

Comment: I checked with another monitor and its VGA cable and it was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this by straightening a bent pin of the VGA connector on the mainboard.